# Something like Apache Zookeeper with no java?

Tags: c++, c, lua, apache-zookeeper

Is there some library or project out there that works like Zookeeper but has no java dependency?  I'm looking at putting this on an embedded linux system, and need minimal footprint... something like a megabyte or less.  I have Lua, C and C++ runtimes, and could put something like NewLISP on there if I had to.  Most or all of the clients will be C or C++, a nice command line utility for the benefit of shell scripts would also be useful.  http://zookeeper.apache.org/

Comment: are you looking to run the client or the server on an embedded system?

Comment: Both.  I have plenty of memory, BTW, but not a lot of code space.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Zookeeper alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6047917/1084416).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZooKeeper alternatives? (cluster coordination service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047917/zookeeper-alternatives-cluster-coordination-service)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [accord](http://www.osrg.net/accord/),

> Accord is a high-performance coordination service like Apache
>   ZooKeeper

It looks like accord is [written in c](https://github.com/collie/accord).

Comment: Aaaand we have a winner... especially since corosync is already on there as well as part of something else.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like corosync is unfortunately loosing support.

Comment: Unfortunately so is Accord.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe check out etcd:

## **[etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd)**

A highly-available key value store for shared configuration and service discovery. etcd is inspired by zookeeper and doozer, with a focus on:

- Simple: curl'able user facing API (HTTP+JSON)
- Secure: optional SSL client cert authentication
- Fast: benchmarked 1000s of writes/s per instance
- Reliable: Properly distributed using Raft

Etcd is written in go and uses the [raft](https://github.com/coreos/go-raft) consensus algorithm to manage a highly availably replicated log.

See [go-etcd](https://github.com/coreos/go-etcd) for a native go client. Or feel free to just use curl, as in the examples below.

Comment: etcd has some serious limits.  Given the scale that CoreOS wants to get to etcd has to scale too. Right now it's too early to tell.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Doozerd](https://github.com/ha/doozerd#readme)
written in Go!

Comment: doozerd is no longer actively maintained.